# no such file in directory python problem and how to fix it

Tags: python

I'm not new to opening an closing files using python but this it refuses to let me access the text files
this is the code ignore the rest just focus on the files parts :

```
def LongFichier(s):
    f=open(s,"r")
    l = len(f.lirelignes())
    f.fermer()
    return(l)
#------------------
def NombreLettresNonMajus(ch):
    n=0
    char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in range(len(ch)) :
        if ch[i] not in char.upper() : 
            n = n+1
    return n 
#------------------
def NombreLettresNonMinus(ch):
    n=0
    char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in range(len(ch)) :
        if ch[i] not in char : 
            n = n+1
    return n 
#------------------
def NombreLettresNonAlph(ch):
    n=0
    char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in range(len(ch)) :
        if ch[i] not in char and ch[i] not in char.upper() : 
            n = n+1
    return n 
#------------------
def plusLongMin(ch):
    char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    n=0
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(ch)) :
        if ch[i] in char : 
            counter = counter+1
            if counter > n :
                n= counter
        else : 
            counter = 0
    return(n)
#------------------
def plusLongMaj(ch):
    char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    n=0
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(ch)) :
        if ch[i] in char.upper() : 
            counter = counter+1
            if counter > n :
                n= counter
        else : 
            counter = 0
    return(n)
#------------------
def CalculScore(ch):
    s=0
    s=s+len(ch)*4
    s=s+( NombreLettresNonMajus(ch))*2
    s=s+( NombreLettresNonMinus(ch))*3
    s=s+NombreLettresNonAlph(ch)*5
    s=s-plusLongMin(ch)*2
    s=s-plusLongMaj(ch)*3
#------------------
def rempPass(s,s2,s3):
    f=open(s2,"r")
    r=open(s,"a")
    oof=open(s3,"a")
    for i in range(LongFichier(s2)) :
        ligne = f.lireligne()
        score = CalculScore(ligne)
        message = ""
        if score <20 : 
            message = "tres faible "
        elif 20<score < 40:
            message = " faible "
        elif 40<score < 60:
            message = " moyen "
        elif 60<score < 80:
            message = " fort "
        if score >= 80:
            message = " tres fort "
            oof.write(ligne+" "+str(score)+" "+message)
        r.write(ligne+" "+str(score)+" "+message)

#------------------
rempPass("school-year\past_bac_exams\2015\passwordScore.txt","school-year\past_bac_exams\2015\password.txt","school-year\past_bac_exams\2015\strongPass.txt")
```

it displays this error :

```
      File "c:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy\school year\past_bac_exams\2015\problem.py", line 88, in <module>
    rempPass("school-year\past_bac_exams\2015\passwordScore.txt","school-year\past_bac_exams\2015\password.txt","school-year\past_bac_exams\2015\strongPass.txt") 
  File "c:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy\school year\past_bac_exams\2015\problem.py", line 67, in rempPass
    f=open(s2,"r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'school-year\\past_bac_exams\x815\\password.txt'
```

I'm sure that the directory path is right because I'm using vscode ( you are able right click on a file and copy its relative path ) so what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi so python consdider \ blackslash as escaping character like \t,\a \n
in this case c:\Users\amine
so please use two blackslash `\\` or one forward slash / like "c:/user/Anime...."